# Youtube API get video query

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api

I've been reading youtube API in orde to find how could I retrieve videos and relavant data about them using a certain query.
I've found this page - https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_api_query_parameters
where there is an example of: https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=surfing&caption&v=2

My question is where should I use my API key ? I don't see any section for this in the query above.

Thanks.

Comment: The URL you mention seems to just deliver a publicly available Atom feed – so why would you want/need to put your API key in there anyway?

Comment: I've read that some queries should use the API key . What is exactly the atom feed and when should I actually use the API key? thanks.

Comment: You should use your API key in situations where it is a) mandatory, or b) has additional benefits. If you want to work with an API, please read its docs.

Answer (score 0):

For the v2 API, you only need your API key if you're uploading video.